# jquery toggleClass duration not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a simple navigation toggle and everything is working except the duration on the toggleClass function when the nav is shown. Can anyone suggest a different approach?

css:

```
.fs-nav {
    display: none;
}

.fs-nav-active {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

jquery/js:

```
$('.fs-nav-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.fs-nav').toggleClass('fs-nav-active', 500);
});
```

Comment: You need jQueryUI for this to work.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Comment: toggleClass doesn't have duration parameter

Comment: @SandraWillford I've added my answer to confirm.

Comment: See tilz0R answer below and accept it if it worked for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include jQuery UI library in order to use `duration` on `toggleClass` function.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's toggleClass don't have a duration parameter. You should use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/) from jQuery UI as user tilzor mentioned.

```
$( ".fs-nav-toggle" ).click(function() {
  $('.fs-nav').toggleClass('fs-nav-active', 500);
});
```